# Application crashes after maven update project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven

I've got a weird problem with Maven in Eclipse. I tried to add some dependency to my project but i failed. To solve this problem I right-clicked on project and selected Maven->Update project in dropdown menu. After that my project crashes whenever I try to run it. I have the following error in LogCat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.my.synch, PID: 16267
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.my.synch/synch.ui.activities.concreteactivities.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "synch.ui.activities.concreteactivities.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.my.synch-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.my.synch-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "synch.ui.activities.concreteactivities.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.my.synch-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.my.synch-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2154)
    ... 11 more
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: Posting your POM or fragments from your project might help diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

do you have your class MainActivity on the path specified on this class not found exception error?

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "synch.ui.activities.concreteactivities.MainActivity"

This error is that maven couldn't find this class.

Comment: MainActivity exists and before i selected "Update Project" option my application worked fine